# I'm trying to register with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, login, user-registration

I have tried this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custome_ajax_email_check', 'custome_ajax_email_check' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custome_ajax_email_check', 'custome_ajax_email_check');

function custome_ajax_email_check(){
   $email = $_POST['user_email'];

   // do check
   if ( email_exists($email) ) {
       $response->result = true;
   }
   else {
       $response->result = false;
   }

   echo( json_encode( $response));
   wp_die();
}


(function($) {
// Register a new user via AJAX
$('#registerform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userLogin = $('#user_reg_login').val();
    var userEmail = $('#user_reg_email').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://neurowebdesign.de/wp-login.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'custome_ajax_email_check',
            user_login: userLogin,
            user_email: userEmail
        },
         success: function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data.result);
                if(data.result) {
                    alert('Email exists!');
                } else {
                    alert('Email does not exist!');

                }
            }
      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But it does not work for me, Can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: `$response` is not defined (as an object) and in PHP 8, it threw this error - `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "result" on null`. So you should just need to fix that issue, however, the REST API has an [endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user) for creating users, so why not use it?

Comment: I am new to Wordpress. Suppose you can show me how I can complete it. It will be a great help to me.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to initialise $response with `$response = new stdClass();` in your AJAX handler before you try and set properties on it. But if you're going to develop for WordPress you'll need to know where to find error messages in your server error log / PHP-fpm log / WordPress debug log.

Comment: But as Sally says if you're trying to register by AJAX why not use the existing REST API? You'll have to handle its error message for email already exists instead of this check.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that, please?